# Spline of data points in 2 axis coordinate system bezierpath

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibezierpath

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the spline of data points in a 2 axis coordinate system to use as a bezierPath (Swift). 
BezierParth needs to have the correct shape and coordinates.

my data look like this and I am after a path like the red line...

Is that even possible?

Thank you in advance

[image: my data look like this]

Comment: Does this has to be absolutely a UIBezierPath or are you simply trying to render a chart on screen?

Comment: UIBezierPath is needed I am afraid.. thank you

Comment: So... no comment as to why my answer was downgraded?  It will be hard to help you if you don't provide feedback

Comment: Hey. I found the answer using OpenCV.. will post the correct answer here once all code is done

Answer (score 1):

In sequence:

1. Sort all your source data points by x
2. Determine how many final data points you want and divide your X axis accordingly, this will determine how "smooth" your bezier is, or if you want it to go up/down on every data point, etc.
3. Compute the average from the source data points into your final data points based on the x distance you computed
4. Organize your final data points into an array
5. Use some magic to render your final data points on a UIBezierPath

There is a really nice article on Medium.com at: https://medium.com/@ramshandilya/draw-smooth-curves-through-a-set-of-points-in-ios-34f6d73c8f9

It goes at length on how to render your UIBezierPath given a set of data points. Luckily, you don't have to understand all that magic, since the writer also made available his source code: https://github.com/Ramshandilya/Bezier